# Multiprocessing: Using `pool.starmap` with large dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

I am doing some computation with `starmap` from `multiprocessing`. Here is what it looks like:

`with Pool(processes=15) as pool:
     results = pool.starmap(fun, [(arg2, arg1, i, dict1, dict2) for i in alist])`

However, from `htop`, the computation is keeping running with single core. Note that dict1 and dict2 are two large dictionary with roughly 5Gb each when loaded into the memory. However, I also observed that the memory occupation already stopped growing, while the program keeps running in single core. Is there any limitation when parallelzing with dictionary. I used this similar approach with large `pandas.DataFrame` and it works fine.

updates: I've done some experiments, which makes me believe this is not a matter of dictionary(I tried replace them with DataFrame, still the same behavior) but the size of the data that get parallelized. Using partial function and `map` also wouldn't help.

Comment: How much memory do you have?

Comment: I have 128Gb @wwii

Comment: How many items an `alist`?  Have you tried making a [partial function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) that includes the static parameters and using it in `starmap`?

Comment: `alist` is more than 100k

Comment: @wwii if I use partial function, then I can just use map instead of starmap?

Comment: @wwii nope, still make the same behavior

Comment: @Darkonaut OK.. Are you saying that the OS is gonna estimate the memory usage first and if the the estimated memory usage is more the what you have, then it is just gonna run with single core?

Comment: I am not so sure why OS need to read and write a lot from disk. Since those two dictionaries are already in memory. I've try much small process number like 3 before. Still the same thing.

Comment: Are you using `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` here?